# How can I diagnose the root cause of a slow screensaver unlock on Yosemite?

Tags: macos, login, screensaver

Several people in our organization are seeing a pronounced pause after entering their password on the login screen after the screen saver / lock has kicked on. It happens regardless of whether the system is coming back from sleep or not. It usually goes:

1. type in password
2. press enter
3. 25% chance of it showing the desktop right away, 75% chance of having to wait about 10 seconds before seeing the desktop

It *might* not be happening when we are not connected to VPN or work network. Can't say for sure.

How can I track down what is causing this slowdown? It's an annoyance more than anything. I would love to get rid of it.

Systems are all MackBook Pros.

Comment: What kinds of computers are in use? What are the settings in the Energy Saver preference pane? My first thought is "Put hard disks to sleep when possible" is checked.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll try that. But I just logged in after getting my system out of my bag and I logged in right away. They're all macbook pros.

Comment: @bneely seems that that didn't do it -- one person who's seeing this issue already had that setting turned off

Comment: You could try looking in the system log. Take note of the time when you click on login and you get the slowdown. After your logged in open up the Applications/Utilities/Console.app and search for the time that you clicked on the login button and read through the system or all logs for anything that may catch your eye as an error or warning. Might not result in anything but it's possible the issue is being recorded.